# Postfix to Gmail and Hotmail

Tags: linux, postfix

I've set up my Postfix mail server with almost everything that I've been reading about:

- DKIM
- DomainKeys
- Reverse DNS
- SPF Records

Everything seems to work (spf=pass, dkim=pass, domainkeys=pass etc). Also, my SMTP seems to pass all diagnosis tests on mxtoolbox.com. Yet for some reason, Gmail and Hotmail keep flagging my messages as spam.

Furthermore, I've also checked my IP to see if it has been black listed but seems that everything's good there too.

After hours of searching through a lot of forums, I'm still not able to find a fix to this. It might be worth noting that my domain name is completely new. Could there be trust issues because of a young domain name?

Another thing is that my domain is hosted on GoDaddy, only the mail server is hosted on a separate machine. Could this be a reason?

I know that this question has been asked many times, but after installing dk-milter for domainkeys and having success with Yahoo mail, I'm clueless about what could possibly be remaining to get messages across to Gmail and Hotmail without them being marked as spam.

Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

> Another thing is that my domain is hosted on GoDaddy, only the mail server is hosted on a separate machine. Could this be a reason?

That shouldn't be an issue at all, unless your SPF record isn't correctly specifying your mail server as an authorized sender.

> Furthermore, I've also checked my IP to see if it has been black listed but seems that everything's good there too.

Gmail uses its own private blacklists, so you wouldn't necessarily be able to query it to see if they're blocking it.

> It might be worth noting that my domain name is completely new. Could there be trust issues because of a young domain name?

No, that shouldn't cause this problem at all.

Are you getting bounceback messages from Gmail/Hotmail? If so, can you include the text of one of those?

Comment: No, the messages aren't bouncing back. It's just that every email sent through my email server is being marked as spam. I've tried using different email accounts but no luck.

Comment: Ah, I see. It sounds like you have things well configured, so I'm not sure what's going on. Being that it's a new domain, you would expect them to be flagging them unless there was something in the body of the email that raised some spam flags.

Comment: On the rDNS, do you have it resolving back to your mail server IP or your GoDaddy hosting IP?

Comment: The rDNS is resolving back to my mail server. I'm starting to suspect that it's due to my domain being a couple of weeks old.

Comment: I've never heard of that happening, but who knows what Google is doing behind the scenes in regards to spam filtering these days.

Comment: Found a link to `Hotmail Deliverability Support Service` (https://support.msn.com/eform.aspx?productKey=edfsmsbl2&ct=eformts). Sumbitted my IP and received an email saying that "reported deliverability problem has been mitigated and might take from 24 to 48 hours to replicate through their systems. Plus additional links to improve my email eco-system. Wow.

Comment: Just an update: even the Hotmail Deliverability Support Service did not help much. My last resort so far has been to join the Junk Mail Reporting Partner program. I don't know if that helps but I've heard that it could take up to a couple of weeks.